# Textbox and variables javascript and HTML

Tags: variables, textbox

I want to set two JavaScript variables as the values of these textboxes.

Can anyone can help me?

```
<form name="myform1"> 
    <input type="number" name="pop_size" value="3"> 
    <input type="button" value="Pop Size" id="population" onclick="setValue()"> 
</form> 
<form name="myform2"> 
    <input type="number" name="totalIterations" value="2"> 
    <input type="button" value="Iterations" id="Iterations" onclick="setValue()"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) to get a list of elements by their names in the form.  Since your names are unique (which isn't necessary in the spec, but is a good idea for this exact reason), the array returned by that function should have exactly one element in it.  Something like this:

```
var firstVariable = document.getElementsByName('pop_size')[0].value;
var secondVariable = document.getElementsByName('totalIterations')[0].value;
```

Or did you mean that you want to set the values to what's in a variable?  That would be the reverse:

```
document.getElementsByName('pop_size')[0].value = firstVariable;
document.getElementsByName('totalIterations')[0].value = secondVariable;
```

Comment: I want put the number in the textbox= variable

Comment: @RuiOliveira: The second version in my answer should do that.  Is it not working?  Are you receiving an error?

Comment: @RuiOliveira: Looks like I had a typo in the second line, the name had an extra capital letter.  That might have been the issue.  (Though I advise you against copying/pasting code from the internet without understanding it or implementing it yourself in general.)  If the error persists, you'll need to be more specific.  Which line generates the error, what part of the line is undefined, maybe reproduce the error in a jsFiddle, etc.